# Возможно ли написать наследника от std::string, запретив ему оператор перемещения и конструктор перемещения? С++

Tags: c++

Хочу потестить функцию push_back с копированием и с перемещением. Но пока зашёл в тупик с использованием std::string. Данный код не компилируется.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class non_move_string : public string
{
public:
    using string::string;
    non_move_string(non_move_string&& other) = delete;
    non_move_string& operator=(non_move_string&& other) = delete;
    non_move_string(const non_move_string& other) = default;
};

class move_string : public string
{
public:
    using string::string;
};

int main()
{
    vector<non_move_string> vec_copy;
    vector<move_string> vec_move;
    auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
        non_move_string tmp("fegerggergerrgrogiergijrgiugjijrvipjfeikq0zdo0ehdoqdocjkovjer9gur9gujiopvbjrpfjrepguj90ghgerg");
        vec_copy.push_back(tmp);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin);
    std::cout << "The time: " << elapsed_ms.count() << " ms\n";

    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
        move_string tmp("fegerggergerrgrogiergijrgiugjijrvipjfeikq0zdo0ehdoqdocjkovjer9gur9gujiopvbjrpfjrepguj90ghgerg");
        vec_move.push_back(tmp);
    }

    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    elapsed_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin);
    std::cout << "The time: " << elapsed_ms.count() << " ms\n";
}
```

Comment: Просто комментарий - не нужно наследоваться от std::string - он для этого не предназначен.

Answer (score 1):

Это сводится вот к чему:

```
non_move_string a;
non_move_string b(std::move(a)); // Ошибка.
```

Компилятор пытается вызвать перемещающий конструктор и не может, потому что он удален.

Лечится убиранием `=delete`-нутых перемещающих операций. Еще забыли добавить `=default` копирующее присваивание.

Перемещающие операции пропадут автоматически, потому что явно созданы копирующие. Но теперь компилятор не будет пытаться их вызвать, а будет заменять копирующими.

---

Что интересно, libstdc++ принимает этот код, а libc++ и MSVC-шная стандартная библиотека - нет. Видимо специальную проверку прикрутили.

Comment: Ну так в этом и суть, чтобы запретить перемещение. Чтобы было только копирование. Я хочу, чтобы компилятор вызывал конструктор копирования. Поэтому я запретил перемещение.

Comment: @VladimirChizh На самом деле вам нужно, чтобы при попытке выполнить перемещение, оно заменялось на копирование. А, то, что вы сделал - тип, для которого копирование работает, а перемещение не компилируется - это просто плохо написанный тип. Не удивительно, что вектор его не проглатывает.

Comment: Ну, а как сделать так, чтобы перемещение на копирование заменялось? Можете код написать?

Comment: @VladimirChizh Ууу... Я же написал. Посмотрите ответ еще раз.

Answer (score -1):

Во первых, хоть и     `std::string`  конструируется с  `const char*`, ваш производный класс не имеет такого конструктора, во вторых, просто пишите соответствующие конструкторы, а не удаляйте их:

```
using std::string;
class non_move_string : public string
{
    
public: 
    non_move_string(const char* str) : string(str){}    
    non_move_string(const non_move_string&) = default;
    non_move_string& operator=(const non_move_string& other)
        = default;
    non_move_string(const non_move_string&& other) noexcept
        : non_move_string(other){}
    non_move_string& 
        operator=(const non_move_string&& other)  noexcept
    {
        *this = other;
        return *this;
    }
};

class move_string : public string
{  
public:
    move_string(const char* str) : string(str){}    
};
```

Comment: Ну первое,  я ж использую область видимости базового класса в наследнике, поэтому от char* все нормально конструируется. А про перемещение, я не хочу, чтобы оно работало. Я хочу его запретить.  Чтобы вызывалось только копирование.

Comment: Когда не могут, помогаем, а когда не хотят _ ничем не поможешь...

Comment: @Vladimir Chizh Дело в том, что `std::vector` в своей реализации использует move-семантику. Если просто запретить перемещение, то программа не будет компилироваться - будет выдавать ошибку. Как вам советуют - переопределив операторы с перемещением, вектор будет вызывать их, а на самом деле будет происходить копирование. Ну или заодно и вектор перепишите свой, а не используйте из стандартной библиотеки.